# bundler/setup (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I cloned a repository and tried to run `rails s`. However, I received the following error:

```
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/me/workspace/bindo/config/boot.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

My ruby version is:

```
ruby 1.9.3p547 (2014-05-14 revision 45962) [x86_64-darwin13.3.0]
```

My `gem env` command run from this project directory:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2014-05-14 patchlevel 547) [x86_64-darwin13.3.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-13
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
     - /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
     - /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

I read on Stack Overflow that this is a path error, however, I am not familiar enough to figure out what to trace or change to make this work. I'm looking but I feel I need some direction.

Comment: `[sudo] gem install bundler && bundler install`

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You likely have `bundler` gem missing.

To get it to work run (first command may need be executed with `sudo`, depending on your environment):

```
[sudo] gem install bundler
bundle install
```

Comment: For windows users, install gem first by using [rubyinstaller + devkit](https://forwardhq.com/help/installing-ruby-windows), do step 1 and 2 then use "gem" in "cmd".

Comment: It didnot work for Mac OS 10.12.6, ruby 1.9.3p551, gem 2.6.13, Rails 3.2.19, Bundler version 1.15.4. Continuing research for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

On the mac, it is possible that you installed gems to `./vendor/bundle`
in order to avoid to use SUDO.
You can find it if you run gem install bundler and at the end of the output you see the following:

```
Using turbolinks-source 5.1.0
Using turbolinks 5.1.0
Using uglifier 4.1.4
Bundle complete! 13 Gemfile dependencies, 68 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
```

If this is the case than in your app root directory delete the bundle directory.
After this run the following commands:

```
[sudo] gem install bundler
bundle install
```

It solved the problem for me