# Cannot run bin/rails s command on OS X YOSEMITE

Tags: ruby

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/veeni/src/noodle/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:7:in `require_relative'
    from bin/rails:7:in `<main>'
```

After running Bundler install the error is now:

> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /var/folders/23/v105s3wd1ggdsl5_jws2jx540000gp/T/bundler20141027-2501-1782y4/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /var/folders/23/v105s3wd1ggdsl5_jws2jx540000gp/T/bundler20141027-2501-1782y4/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/extensions/universal-darwin-14/2.0.0/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/gem_make.out An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.3.1), and Bundler
>   cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.3.1'`
>   succeeds before bundling.

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560725/bundler-setup-loaderror

Comment: Hi guys, I'm sorry but I tried that, it does not solve the issue and instead it gave a new error that nokogiri cannot be installed.

Answer (score 1):

You likely have `bundler` gem missing.

To get it to work run (first command may need be executed with `sudo`, depending on your environment):

```
[sudo] gem install bundler
bundler install
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your willingness to assist, there's a new error : '
Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/23/v105s3wd1ggdsl5_jws2jx540000gp/T/bundler20141027-2501-1782y4/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/folders/23/v105s3wd1ggdsl5_jws2jx540000gp/T/bundler20141027-2501-1782y4/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/extensions/universal-darwin-14/2.0.0/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.3.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.3.1'` succeeds before bundling.'

Comment: Try to install `nokogiri` as suggested, examine errors (I bet there is no `libxml-dev` installed on your machine,) fix that error and you are done.