# When making a new Rails app, I get the following error: `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rbenv

I've seen a couple other similar questions, but no solutions. When I create my new Rails app, I receive the following error:

`/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in 'require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)`

Tried `gem install bundler && bundler install` and I get:

`Successfully installed bundler-1.10.6
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.10.6
Done installing documentation for bundler after 6 seconds
1 gem installed
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory`

The app is still created and works, but I don't know why I'm getting the error. Please let me know if you need more specific information to provide an answer. This is my first post to stackoverflow, so I'm still learning. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bundler/setup (LoadError)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560725/bundler-setup-loaderror)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running into the same problem today.

I was running ruby 2.2.1 (via rbenv) and rails 4.2.1.

In the end I installed ruby 2.2.2 (via rbenv). I then installed rails 4.2.5. `rails new` then worked without problem.

So I don't know what the underlying problem is, but maybe this will be helpful to someone.

Comment: This worked! No idea why, but thanks for sending that over, @Kenshi

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you have not installed the Bundler Gem. Try running the following in your terminal:

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

Bundler is Ruby's package manager.

---

From Bundler.io:

"Bundler provides a consistent environment for Ruby projects by tracking and installing the exact gems and versions that are needed.

Bundler is an exit from dependency hell, and ensures that the gems you need are present in development, staging, and production. Starting work on a project is as simple as bundle install."

Comment: I tried the first line `gem install bundler` and it seemed to successfully install `bundler-1.10.6`, but when I do `bundle install`, it says: `Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory`

Answer (score 0):

You have to install bundler first.

```
$ gem install bundler
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried this and it worked. But then I did `bundle install` and received the following error: `Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory`

Answer (score -1):

> cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)

Ruby is looking for a ruby source file named `bundler.rb` and can't find it. Ruby looks for files in the directories listed in the global variable `$LOAD_PATH`.

You probably just need to `gem install bundler`

Comment: So I tried `gem install bundler` and it seems to have successfully installed `bundler-1.10.6` but then when I got to create a new app again, I get the same error. I'm creating a new app by going: `rails new test-app`

Comment: I've never gotten this error before in the past, but I recently updated RubyGems like so: `gem update --system` Not sure if maybe that triggered something?

Comment: Check your `$LOAD_PATH` in `irb` and see if you can find `bundler.rb` manually.

Comment: Hmm...it doesn't look like it's there. Should I try adding `bundler.rb` to it?

Comment: If `bundler.rb` isn't in your `$LOAD_PATH`, then you can't `require` it. You're sure you installed bundler? Sorry you're having trouble with this, it's not supposed to be so hard. If you can't figure it out, this video may help: http://confreaks.tv/videos/railsconf2015-how-does-bundler-work-anyway

Comment: Yeah, I definitely have bundler installed. I guess I just needed to update ruby and Rails. Thanks for all your help, @Jared!

Answer (score -1):

I understand that u've installed bundler already. i think that you might have installed bundler to specific gemset.

Try installing bundler to global gemset using `rvm gemset use global && gem install bundler`.

Comment: I don't think I have the `rvm` command. I received the error: `-bash: rvm: command not found`. Should I try to use a different command?

Comment: @nwu , This method is for people who installed rvm in their machine. if you don't have rvm installed, then install it first and then try the above method.