# Bundler doesn't work although it is installed as a local gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, bundler, redmine, offline

I try installing Redmine (that means ruby and rails) on my OFFLINE ubuntu 14.04.

I installed ruby OK, compiling from source:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]
```

I installed bundler, creating the gem thanks to rake and then installing the gem:

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (default: 1.3.0)
bundler (2.0.0.dev)
did_you_mean (1.1.0)
io-console (default: 0.4.6)
json (default: 2.0.2)
minitest (5.10.1)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
openssl (default: 2.0.3)
power_assert (0.4.1)
psych (default: 2.2.2)
rake (12.0.0)
rdoc (default: 5.0.0)
test-unit (3.2.3)
xmlrpc (0.2.1)
```

I then want to install downloaded gems locally, but bundler doesn't seem to be installed. When I check, it is apparently the case:

```
$ bundle -v
/usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.0.dev/exe/bundle:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

How can I solve this?
Thanks a lot

César

Comment: Are you using any Ruby version management tool? like rvm, rbenv or chruby etc...

Comment: Check these answers, if they help [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19099768/2968762), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26560950/2968762)

Comment: You have to execute `bundle install` in your project directory, may be this is causing the issue.

Comment: @Mohanraj : no, I'm 100% offline. Thanks.

Comment: @Abhi : yes, I already checked these ones... Link1 doesn't apply and neither Link 2because I'm offline and I've already installed bundler as "gem list" shows. Thanks anyway.