# error `require' /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I installed ubuntu and want to install Ruby on Rails. But tried few times and see same error after I run 'rails new app' I see error

```
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
```

The server also doesn't run because of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bundler/setup (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560725/bundler-setup-loaderror)

Answer (score 2):

You need to install [Bundler](https://bundler.io/) first.

```
gem install bundler
```

Bundler is a Ruby gem. It's a Ruby gem used to manage other Ruby gems (often called dependencies).

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

can you try below command?

> echo $GEM_PATH

and check the ruby version, Is that different version then ruby/2.5.0?

and if it's different then set your $GEM_PATH from below command.

```
SetEnv GEM_HOME /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8(set your path)
```

Comment: I have ruby-2.5.5. "SetEnv GEM_HOME /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8(set your path)" I'm not sure which path I should specify here.

Comment: see in your error log it try to find ruby-2.5.0. here /usr/lib **/ruby/2.5.0/** rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'. you have to set to path for ruby-2.5.5.

Comment: after that, you can see you all ruby version which are installed in your PC using **rvm list** command and set current version using **rvm use 2.5.5** command and it's done. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use

```
gem install os
```

Comment: And you'd better add sudo.